# kendojs template data-bind click event not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Well, I am using KendoJS grid and I have this code here in my .js file:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({

    people: new kendo.data.DataSource(...),

    isActive:true,
    friends: new kendo.data.DataSource(...),
    selectionChanged: function(){...
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.bind($("#sampleGridContainer"), viewModel);
});
```

In my .html file, I have a kendo grid:

```
<div id="sampleGridContainer">
    <div data-role="grid"
         data-columns="[...]"
         data-editable="{ 'mode': 'popup', 'template': kendo.template($('#sampleTemplate').html()) }"
         data-bind="source: people"></div>
</div>


<script id="sampleTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <form id="sampleForm">
       ...

       <div data-container-for="somedropdown" class="k-edit-field">
            <input name="somedropdown" id="somedropdown"
                 data-role="dropdownlist"
                 data-type="text"
                 data-text-field="name"
                 data-value-field="value"
                 data-bind="value: someValue, visible: isActive, source: friends, click: selectionChanged" />
       </div>           

       ...
    </form>
</script>
```

Now, in my dropdown `input` element, `someValue`, `isActive` and `friends` variables are properly working - infact the drop down list shows up fine. But the problem is click event `selectionChanged` is not called. If I remove this from template, the event starts working, but my question is when all the other variables on the same scope are accessible in template, why does event `selectionChanged` not get called?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem, my workaround for this is that I initialize my `kendoDropDownList` on the `edit` event of grid.

```
edit: function (e){
   e.container.find("input[name='somedropdown']").kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "name",
      dataValueField: "value",
      data-bind="value: viewModel.someValue, visible: viewModel.isActive, source: viewModel.friends, click: viewModel.selectionChanged"
   });
}
```

Then the html would look something like this:

```
<div data-role="grid"
   data-columns="[...]"
   data-editable="{ 'mode': 'popup', 'template': kendo.template($('#sampleTemplate').html()) }"
   data-bind="source: people, events: { edit: onEdit }">
</div>

<script id="sampleTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <form id="sampleForm">
       <div data-container-for="somedropdown" class="k-edit-field">
            <input name="somedropdown"/>
       </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, I have already got that working that way, but because of lots of down downs, the edit method is full of redundant  code. I was just wondering why is everything else accessible (on the same scope) except the functions.